# FOR XML ... TYPE much slower than FOR XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

Running `SQL Server 2014`. I have a stored procedure that returns a quite large `XML`. It goes something like this:

```
SELECT(
   ...
   FOR XML PATH (N''), ROOT, TYPE
```

Now, that query runs in 1 second. If I remove `TYPE` it runs in around half the time:

```
SELECT(
   ...
   FOR XML PATH (N''), ROOT
```

Obviously, the latter returns an `nvarchar(max)` instead of an `xml`. I want xml data, but if I ask for xml it gets slower! If I want to fetch xml data on the client, is it really necessary to convert it to xml using the `TYPE` directive above?

**Q:** Anyway, why is `FOR XML ... TYPE` **significantly** slower than `FOR XML ...`? Is there any way to improve the conversion?

Comment: First, 2 times difference isn't usually considered significant in the database world. The difference between `PATH()` and `AUTO()` modes, for example, is significant. Second, have you tried to compare them by running in the reverse order, and / or with cold data cache?

Comment: I dropped the stored procedure between the runs. Should reset any cache, no? So would `AUTO` be faster?

Comment: No, I mean using `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` after each execution to ensure that no data cached previously would skew the comparison.

Comment: And `for xml auto()` usually tends to be much slower than `path()`, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set variables with the results as XML and as VARCHAR(MAX) **without** displaying them? Maybe the time difference you measure is bound to preparing the viewer? Pasting the first letters into a grid column is faster than creating a well formed, indented, displayable XML...

Sepcifying "TYPE" is not needed in most cases. You really **need** this with nested XML only. Just play around with aliases, PATH- and ROOT-literals and - of course - with or without TYPE:

And - very important! - try to call this with the surrounding SELECT and without:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT tbls.TABLE_NAME AS [@TableName]
          ,(
             SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS [@ColumName]
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS cols 
             WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME=Tbls.TABLE_NAME
             FOR XML PATH('COLUMN') /*,TYPE*/ 
           ) /*AS alias*/
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS Tbls
    FOR XML PATH('TABLE'),ROOT('ALL_TABLES') /*,TYPE*/ 
) /*AS alias*/
```

I don't know, how you continue with your generated XML. If you transfer it to your application it will be a plain string anyway.

Conclusio: Take the faster approach :-)

By the way...

I do not know your Stored Procedure and what else is done there besides the SELECT...

In most cases it is a bad habit to use SPs just to read data.

If your SP is not more than a wrapper around your SELECT you should think about a (single-statement!) table valued function to retrieve your data.

This function is easily queried and transformed to XML with

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyFunction(/*Parameters*/)
FOR XML PATH('TheRowsName'),ROOT('TheRootName') [,TYPE]
```

Or - if you need this as XML everytime, you might define a scalar function delivering XML or VARCHAR(MAX). The re-usability of functions is way better than with SPs...

Comment: I concluded that it is the conversion to xml that takes time. I'm wondering if the conversion gives you anything of value. Xml syntax validation perhaps?

Comment: @l33t, yes XML conversions gives you validation. But you can rely on `FOR XML PATH()` creating valid XML in any case, so there's no extra value. Did you try the example of my answer? The biggest difference is the way a nested (sub)select is integrated in surrounding XML.

Comment: Will try it as soon as I can! Since the xml is already validated I would be surprised if the conversion is indeed slow. Maybe SSMS takes some time to render/initialize the cell with xml. But I don't see how that can affect `STATISTICS TIME`.

Comment: @l33t I was curious. I just tried four calls, all with a following `dbcc dropcleanbuffers`: Without TYPE, with TYPE, again with TYPE and again without TYPE. All four calls take 25% of the time and lead to identical Execution Plans. So - as expected - the difference comes from somewhere else...